# Amazon SageMaker input data?

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ml

I am exploring Amazon SageMaker as a scalable machine learning solution.

My question is; is it required that the training data first be uploaded in Amazon S3?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the built-in models pull from S3 and write the computed model back to S3.